The difficulties with reading Hume

They [some special kind of philosophers] think it a reproach to all literature, that philosophy should not yet have fixed, beyond controversy, the foundation of morals, reasoning, and criticism; and should for ever talk of truth and falsehood, vice and virtue, beauty and deformity, without being able to determine the source of these distinctions.

It's from Hume's "Enquiry concerning human understanding".
I have troubles with understanding this passage.
By "philosophy should not yet have fixed the foundations of morals", does Hume mean that philosophy did not have the obligation to fix this foundations yet?

Hume does not suggest that philosophy is excused from the obligation to "fix" these foundations; rather, he observes that it has failed to do so thus far. This failure is seen as a deficiency by certain critics, and Hume uses this as an opportunity to examine whether these foundations can be better understood through his empirical approach.

@MauroALLEGRANZA then the usage of "should" is not very clear for me. Can you explain what's the difference with "Philosophy has not yet fix the foundations"? What does the verb "should" adds to the meaning? And what about "should not"?

Hume says "they think it a reproach" without necessarily committing himself to the opinion, although he does proceed to defend the virtues of "accurate and abstract" philosophy here described in later passages. But even assuming he concurs, the "should not yet have" is a fanciful turn of phrase, where "should" does not mean obligation to not yet have. It rather puts emphasis on not yet having being reproachable. Compare to "that you should think this funny is deplorable". In both cases, "should" can be dropped without changing the literal meaning, but not without losing the edge.

@ЕгорГалыкин recommend you ask about the use of "should" in this way on English Stackexchange.  The use of the term in this way is not very common in current American parlance, but is or was common.  Maybe it's an older or British usage?  At least, it's not a specifically "philosophy" usage of "should".

I think it a reproach to all good manners that the community here should not yet have answered you appropriately other than in the comments.
In addtion to what was mentioned in the comments, 'should' is here used in the sense of a personal judgement.
As in: It is shameful that he should ask you for money.
This use is peculiar to British English. In American English 'would' is more commmonly used.
Hume was, of course, Scottish.
